# Find the max of a group in one column then reference another column value in that row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm working with a data frame that has multiple groups. I want to find the maximum value of a group in one column and then reference the value of another column in that same row in order to populate a new column.

Example:

```
item   group  val1   val2
<chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a      1      1      1
2 b      1      2      3
3 c      1      3      2
4 d      2      1      0
5 e      2      2      1
```

For each group, I want to take the max Val1 and populate a new column with that row's Val2. So the example would become:

```
item   group  val1   val2   val3
<chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a      1      1      1      2
2 b      1      2      3      2
3 c      1      3      2      2
4 d      2      1      0      1
5 e      2      2      1      1
```

Finding the max of a group is easy but I can't figure out how to reference another value in the row and populate using that instead. Been googling all day. This is what I have tried that returns a column of NAs instead of val2 values:

```
library(tidyverse)
item <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
group <- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2")
val1 <- c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2")
val2 <- c("1", "3", "2", "0", "1")
data <- tibble(item = item,
           group = group,
           val1 = val1,
           val2 = val2)

data %>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(val3 = max(val1)["val2"]) -> data
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

You may try

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(val3 = val2[which.max(val1)])

  item  group val1  val2  val3 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     1     1     1     2    
2 b     1     2     3     2    
3 c     1     3     2     2    
4 d     2     1     0     1    
5 e     2     2     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could give this a try:

```
data %>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(var3, data[data$val1 == max(val1)]$val2) -> data
```